# NPM Pug is not working in my JS application

Tags: node.js, pug

I am trying to use pug in my node application since Jade is now deprecated and my app.js looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var app = express();

// tells which folder the template files will be in
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

app.listen(3000);

console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
```

I created a views folder and inside that folder I have my index.pug file.

When I run the site in the browser, I do not see the hello world.

How can I use pug in my site?

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages in the server console or in the frontend console?

Answer (score 3):

your code is correct and perfectly working just give correct path on below line

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
```

if your view folder is inside public or in any other folder set path of that folder like this:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './public/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
```

or remove all dependencies and reinstall them again
Or their might be fault in indentation in index.pug page

if it is not working change the function to this

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('hello world');
});
```